# Dynamic page number in page item reference

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have seen several mentions of using APP_PAGE_ID as a reference to the current page. Is there a way to use this variable (or anything else) to dynamically refer to page items without calling out the page number?

Example: The application has items P1_NAME and P2_NAME on pages 1 and 2, respectively. If an identical process is performed on each item on their pages, is there a way to write the variable in the processes as something akin to APP_PAGE_ID_NAME, so the items don't need to be replaced in the code as long as they have consistent naming conventions?

Comment: no, you need to use a stored procedure or a function and pass each item as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use substitution string in APEX, for e.g. P **&APP_PAGE_ID.** _NAME

Other option, in case you want to access page id in a process, reference the item using V function. for e.g. dbms_output.put_line(V('P' || **V('APP_PAGE_ID')** || '_NAME'));

Follow this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24plsql-2100063.html), has very good information on how write plsql in APEX.

Comment: I was missing the P before the substitution string; this seems to do the trick. Thanks!